# Unable to use Chromium browser

Tags: raspbian-stretch, pi-3b+, chromium

I have a Raspberry Pi 3 B+ with Raspbian installed. I use it headlessly with Remote Desktop Connection with Windows 10. After I log on to the Pi, my home screen shows up. If I run the Chromium browser after that, it shows me the Chromium home screen. However, the moment I enter a URL and run it, the CPU monitor on the top right shows that the CPU usage level increases and eventually it hangs and terminates the connection to my computer. Because of this, I cannot use the Internet on my Raspberry Pi. What should I do?

Comment: Are you using the latest Raspbian Buster, fully updated?

Comment: No, I'm using Raspbian Stretch. I'm not sure if it's fully updated.

Comment: Firstly either re-flash your existing sd card or a new sd card with Raspbian Buster so that you have the latest software.

Comment: @CoderMike Done.

Comment: I've set it up with SSH, Remote Desktop Connection and I took the advice of @Milliways and set up VNC too.

Comment: Did using the latest software make any difference? What power supply are you using?

Comment: Yes, the Chromium browser now works better and it no longer crashes, although the Pi heats up a little bit. So problem solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your using the very latest software.

Either re-flash your existing sd card or a new sd card with Raspbian Buster.

Then update with:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt full-upgrade -y
```